# radio button does not stay pushed

Tags: ruby-on-rails, radio-button, ransack

I am useing ransack and radiobuttons in a search form:

```
<%= search_form_for @search, :html => {:class => "form-inline"} do |f| %>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.radio_button :statusdate2_lt, Date.current %>
    <%= f.label :statusdate2_lt, "Overdue" %>
    <br/>
    <br/>
    <%= f.radio_button :salespaydate_null, "1" %>
    <%= f.label :salespaydate_null, "Salespaydate empty" %>
    <br/>
    <br/>
    <%= f.radio_button :status_gt, 0 %>
    <%= f.label :status_gt, "Product aligned" %>
  </div>
  <br/>
  <div class="action">
    <%= f.submit "Select", class: "btn btn-primary" %> 
    <%= link_to "Reset", products_path, class: "btn btn-primary" %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

I get a weird behaviour. Two of the buttons (the first and the third) keep their pressed state when the select button is pushed and the page reloaded. the middle forgets it and is unpushed. the ransack filter for the button is transmitted and applied though.

After the page load the relevant html looks like this (obvously, I guess):

```
<input checked="checked" id="q_statusdate2_lt_2013-07-16" name="q[statusdate2_lt]" type="radio" value="2013-07-16" />
<label for="q_statusdate2_lt">Overdue</label>
<br/>
<br/>
<input id="q_salespaydate_null_1" name="q[salespaydate_null]" type="radio" value="1" />
<label for="q_salespaydate_null">Salespaydate empty</label>
<br/>
<br/>
<input checked="checked" id="q_status_gt_0" name="q[status_gt]" type="radio" value="0" />
<label for="q_status_gt">Product aligned</label>
```

Comment: Can you add whole form code?

Comment: Is this value properly saved to the db? Can you add object `.inspect`?

Comment: @MichaelSzyndel The whole form is here: https://gist.github.com/kgeo/39a73a85805dfa66b548